# Can not set minimumFractionDigits of toLocaleString()

Tags: javascript

I try to use toLocaleString() to format my number but it can not do it.

```js
var number = 123.456;
console.log(number.toLocaleString('en-GB', {minimumFractionDigits: 1}));
```

My result need to be 123.4

But it always is 123.456

Answer (score 16):

Set the `maximumFractionDigits` in the options object.

```
var number = 123.456;
console.log(number.toLocaleString('en-GB', {maximumFractionDigits: 1}));
```

Also, note that the number will  be rounded.

Comment: If I set maximumFractionDigits: 4. But in IE 9-10, it can not work. It always have 2 decimals (123.46). How can I fix it?

Comment: @MinhNguyen You'll have to use some other workaround, because this kind of formatting is not supported in IE 9-10. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Answer (score 6):

Just in case if someone else is facing the same issue, those options worked fine for me:

```
Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', { maximumFractionDigits: 2, minimumFractionDigits: 2, style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' }).format(value)
```

where `value` is what you want to format.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to set the decimal places of the float number, you can use the [toFixed()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) function. Following an example:

```
var number = 123.456;
var result = number.toFixed(1); /// number of decimal places as parameter
```

Comment: I knew that solution. But I need to set locale too.

Comment: Oh, sorry.. so, the solution is set the maximumFractionDigits, as turnt said

Answer (score 0):

```
var number = 123.456;
var opts = {maximumSignificantDigits: 3};
console.log(number.toLocaleString('en-GB', opts));
```